# SC4503 Step Up Switching Regulator Design: Why is output unregulated?

Tags: switching-regulator

I am working on a PCB design with the Semtech SC4503 1.3MHz Step-Up Switching Regulator to regulate an input from 4V to 10V to a constant 5V output.

I have printed a prototype PCB, but the circuit is not working as expected—the output voltage is the same as in the input voltage. Additionally, the Shutdown function does not work; the output voltage remains the same as the input voltage, event when I drive the _SHDN pin low to GND.

With an input voltage of 3.0V, I measured the Feedback voltage at 0.68V, output voltage of 2.7V.  If the output was 5V, the feedback voltage should be 1.25V based on feedback resistor selection.

Is there some minimum value for the feedback resistors that should be used with the SC4503?  Are my selections of inductor (Bourns SRR4028-4R7Y) and schottky diode (ON Semiconductor MBRM130LT1G) acceptable?

Pasted below is my schematic, PCB layout (red = top layer, blue = bottom layer; bottom layer is ground plane), and components list.

Thank you,
Hal

[image: SC4503 Design Schematic] 
[image: SC4503 PCB Layout]
[image: SC4503 Design Component List]

Comment: Addressing your question about shutdown is easy - look at the current path: from power in, through L2, through D7, to power out. There's nothing the IC can do to prevent that. The shutdown function will only stop the IC from performing its boost operation.

Comment: for the case of 3 V input, was the boost IC switching? what is the observed switching frequency? check whether it is getting enabled.

Comment: Ensure that the shutdown pin-4 is not left floating. It must be pulled high for the IC to operate.

Comment: brhans, thanks for the response. The SC4503 datasheet states pulling the _SHDN pin below 0.4V shuts down the regulator.  If the SC4503 pulls the SW pin low in Shutdown mode, wouldn't the output be 0v?

Comment: Umar, thank you.  With a 3.0V input, the voltage at the SW pin is not switching--it is approximately 2.7V, constant.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your title. This is a step-up regulator. It cannot step down.

Look at your schematic. D7 is in series with the inductor to the output so you have low impedance path directly between input and output when the input is greater than the desired output by more than a few hundred mV.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Spehro.  Point taken on the SC4503 only serving as a step-up regulator.  But even when I input 3.0V to the SC4503 in my circuit, the output is 2.7V, so it seems something is wrong with my design.

Comment: I based my design on the reference design in the SC4503 datasheet (Figure 1(a)).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the circuit. If pin 1 is open or possibly if the chip is damaged that would be the result.

Comment: Spehro, you were right, I had a bad pin connection.  The circuit now functions correctly--a 3.3V input produces a 5V output.  Is there a way I can implement a true shutdown mode?  Perhaps by inserting a capacitor between the inductor and the diode so that only high frequency switching will pass the diode when the device is enabled?

Comment: High-side switch in front of the regulator (a couple transistors) will allow this.